Temperature dependent characteristics of a diode

I understand why the forward voltage decreases in the diode due to the increase in temperature (since the intrinsic carrier increases and that decreases the voltage since intrinsic carrier and the forward voltage are inversely proportional,) but what about the point where it all coincides, and after that the corresponding current flow  at forward voltage 2.0 (for instance) for lower temperature has the higher forward current and the higher temperature has reduced current? A whole comprehensive explanation is appreciated.

these figures are so small, nobody could read anything from them…

Fredrick - Hi, Where did the image come from? To comply with the site rule on referencing, details of the original source of copied / adapted material must be provided by you, next to each item. If the original source is online (webpage, PDF, video etc.) please [edit] the question & add its name & link (URL) (e.g. website name + PDF title + its URL). If the original source was a book or other offline material, please [edit] the question & add the best reference you can e.g. title, author(s), page, edition etc. TY

Sure I'll do them. and the figure seemed good first, now I realized it's blurred. apologies

Ohmic resistance of the crystal and contacts dominates the voltage drop at high current. For most materials, resistance increases with temperature.

Yes! + In high temperatures, acoustic phonon scattering dominates, reducing the mobility of charge carriers, and reducing the current.

Your SiC diodes have lots of bulk resistance which has a positive temperature coefficient. At high currents this more than offsets the neg temp co of the semiconductor junction. When you are past the curve crossover in the positive temperature coefficient range you will get good current sharing of paralleled devices but beware the whole heatsink assembly can runaway. A temp sensor on the heatsink would save the diodes by backing off the current or shutting down if things get too hot.
